# Keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input

Tags: ssl

This question may be duplicate, but i am not able to get the solution,
I tried to create SSL certificate with following commands,

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin>keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
-keystore E:\key
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  Raghu
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  BFS
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  iGate
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Bang
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  KA
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  IN
Is CN=Raghu, OU=BFS, O=iGate, L=Bang, ST=KA, C=IN correct?
  [no]:  y

Enter key password for <tomcat>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:
```

I have tried get certificate request using following command

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin>keytool -certreq -v -alias tomcat -keyalg
RSA -keystore E:\key
Enter keystore password:
```

And got following response in the command prompt

```
**-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- MIIBlzCCAQACAQAwVzELMAkGA1UEBhMCSU4xCzAJBgNVBAgTAktBMQ0wCwYDVQQHEwRCYW5nMQ4w
DAYDVQQKEwVpR2F0ZTEMMAoGA1UECxMDQkZTMQ4wDAYDVQQDEwVSYWdodTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEA0Aoxz2V/Cqs00d7d4iVysIcfMxXDA4ydD5+AY2Q2hPqIOAbfrz0HiSjZ
JwKV0/g7P/oWPU9fCFYnLXAynusbaAtw5xIolMNqj9gtxmD1BzrwxcVIX3oWY0LzO768TMY3Szjp
tS64z5q1KSTYqeZww0f11N2JssjtMch8gw50FIcCAwEAAaAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAK1v
sE0BNxGrGKNBXhYuSdgwF14ZnELtjWBzDJDzbzgJbK6RJlOEstKxdStR2fq7iv0ow+Df7TnVWidm
+0PRLuhtr3DMZVX2acNQY4c4ynKWgLyBV2lAXbYfgZdzQr3ClY+40lkbmHQaMxZcxz2q7u8Np6sH
n0iytY6U0CqJpRcB
----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----**
```

And I am saved in cert.txt file and to Verify the Certificate Reply

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin>keytool -printcert -file E:\cert.txt

**keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input**
```

I got the above error. please suggest for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed one step which is causing the issue.

```
keytool -exportcert -rfc -keystore D:\key -file D:\cert.crt
```

Please check this [link](http://www.techpaste.com/2013/07/keytool-error-java-lang-exception-failed-parse-input-keytool/).

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing *certificate* and *certificate request*.

When you use `-certreq`, you're producing a certificate request (CSR), which you should send to your CA, which will send you a certificate in return. You'll then be able to import that certificate into your keystore, against the private key it already holds (and that was generated with `-genkey`.

`-printcert` is for printing certificates, not certificate requests (`BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST`).

Comment: Please suggest me what to do now?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get a certificate from a CA or a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Self-Signed Certificate

Comment: In this case, export the certificate, not the CSR: use `-exportcert` instead (`-genkey` generates both a certificate internally and a CSR). You'll also need to put your host name in "*What is your first and last name?*" (e.g. `www.example.com`): this is what will be used for the CN.